# How to construct potential form for adjectives

Tags: adjectives, potential-form

I could not help but notice that adjectives cannot directly conjugate to have a potential form:

> E.g. `赤い` **does not** become `赤られる` for (can be red)

**(Question)** Which of the below are acceptable forms to convey a potential for adjectives? What about な-adjectives?:

> - 赤く出来る (using potential-form of する)
> - 赤くなれる (using potential-form of なる) (This seems to mean "can become red" which is so very different from "can be red")
> - EDIT: 赤いがなり得る (I found this construction, I'm not sure what it does and how different it is from 赤くなれる and 赤くなり得る)
> - 赤いことができる　(Using the sentence pattern ～ことができる)
>
> I also thought about using the copula but there isn't any potential form for だ/です. Unless it's であられる?
>
> - Would 赤いであられる make sense for "can be red" ?

Comment: I'd personally write 「赤い可能性がある」 ("red is a possibility")

Comment: なる/なれる means a lot more than "to become"... and is often a lot more natural than です/ある to express a potential state of being.

Comment: @cypher That only conveys possibility. What about ability?

Comment: I'm not sure, but `赤くいられる` sounds possible to me (I don't know if that's valid or not, but searching Google you can find examples of it, e.g. `雪の下でも赤くいられる実` presumably meaning "the fruit is able to be red even under the snow") I'm just taking punts here, I don't really know for sure :P

Comment: `赤くできる` gets the most results of the queries I tried, `赤く可能` (possible to be red), `赤く能力` (ability to be red), even `赤く機能` (the feature of being able to be red?) also sound plausible to me.

Comment: How is "able to be red" different from "possibly red"? The only way I can think of is if the thing in question chooses its own colour...

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I used 赤い to represent い-adjectives in general. Perhaps if something like かわいい was used instead. Then "able to be cute" and "possibly cute" would be very different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by “potential form.”

Both れる/られる and ことができる are attached to a verb and their basic meaning is “have the ability to do.”  (れる/られる has very different meanings such as passive and respect, but I ignore them for the purpose of this answer.)  Because they are about the ability, the subject is usually animate.

The combination of ある+られる would be あられる, but this combination is ungrammatical for a reason I do not know.

Although the meaning of れる/られる/ことができる has large overlap with the meaning of “can” in English, it does not cover the usage of “can” in “can be red” (= may be red; possibly be red).

“Possibly” can be translated as “～可能性がある” as cypher wrote in a comment, or “～かもしれない.”  Therefore, “can be red” is 赤い可能性がある or 赤いかもしれない.  Although 可能性がある and かもしれない are not completely the same, I am not prepared to explain the difference now.

Below I will try to explain whether each of your examples is grammatical or not and what its meaning is.

- 赤くする is “redden (something),” and 赤くできる (or 赤く出来る, although できる in this usage is usually written in hiragana) is “have the ability of redden (something).”
- 赤くなれる is “have the ability to turn red,” but I do not know when it can be used.
- 赤くなりうる is “possibly turn red.”  Unlike 可能性がある and かもしれない, [得]{う}る in this meaning can be only attached to a verb.
- 赤いがなり得る is ungrammatical because 赤いがなる is ungrammatical.
- 赤いことができる is ungrammatical because ことができる can be only attached to a verb as I wrote above.
- 赤いであられる is ungrammatical for two reasons: 赤いである is ungrammatical, and the combination あられる is somehow ungrammatical as I wrote above.

Comment: I chose `赤い` because it was the first adjective to appear in my mind. So I used to to represent all い-adjectives. If you find it better to use other adjectives to explain then it would be good. I'm not expecting answers to be restricted to `赤い`. If you could provide some examples of common usage of each case it would be great. Thanks =D

Comment: @Flaw: That is beyond both my ability and my time constraint.  For example, there are at least two meanings for adjective+する and probably more, and there are too many possible ways to turn adjective+する into something related potential for me to explain.

Comment: Perhaps when you get the inspiration to furnish your answer then. I'll look forward to that. Until then your current answer will have to do.

Comment: @Flaw: Or when someone else posts a more comprehensive answer.  I look forward to that. :)