# expressing casual potential for adjectives

Tags: i-adjectives, potential-form

This is a follow up to [How to construct potential form for adjectives](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3760/how-to-construct-potential-form-for-adjectives)

I'd like to know how to say "can be x" where x is an adjective, in a casual way. For example with a friend, this seems a little stiff: "敬語凄い長い可能性があるね。” ("Keigo can be really long.")  Isn't there a casual term more relevant for this situation? かもしれない doesn't seem relevant as I'm not expressing doubt.

Comment: can you write what you wanted to express in english as well please?

Comment: Were you trying to say "keigo （敬語） can be really long"?

Comment: I've never really thought about a "potential form for 
adjectives" before and this is just my instinct so I'll put it as a comment but... what about something like ～長くなったりするよね or  ～ときもあるよね?

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to say that keigo can be really long. I guess "can" has a ton of uses in English and trying to wrap them all up in a "potential form" is not productive. I think ～ときもあるよね is a good way to express what I'm trying to say. I guess this question is resolved then, but I'm not really sure how to mark it as such other than deleting it.

Comment: You could also use `〜こと(は・が・も)ある`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original sentence sounds better as

> 敬語は凄く長くなる可能性がある。

I guess that means that in Japanese it sounds more natural to say

> Keigo can *get* very long.

rather than

> Keigo can *be* very long.

To make that less formal, you could try to omit 可能性, i.e.

> 敬語は凄く長くなるよね。
>   Keigo gets really long (sometimes).

Other ways of saying the same thing (plagiarised from @istrasci) would include

> 敬語は凄く長いことがある。
>   Sometimes keigo is very long.